# Caret "Metric RMSE not applicable for classification models" when data is continuous

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, lasso, caret

I am running into an error trying to train a caret model with method='glmnet.' My data is continuous and I am trying to do a LASSO regression, but the existence of a 0 for one of the observations is causing the error "Metric RMSE not applicable for classification models." When I remove the 0 observation, everything works fine. The code below reproduces the error.

```
library(caret)
library(glmnet)

x_t = matrix(rnorm(100*20), 100, 20)
colnames(x_t) = paste("X", 1:ncol(x_t), sep="")

y_t = matrix(rnorm(100))
y_t[30] = 0

sample_lasso = caret::train(method="glmnet", x=x_t, y=y_t) #throws error: Metric RMSE not applicable for classification models
sample_lasso = caret::train(method="glmnet", x=x_t[-30, ], y=y_t[-30]) #works as expected
```

Any help would be much appreciated. It's quite strange, as caret seemingly recognizes this is a regression problem by automatically setting metric="RMSE." Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero value is not causing the error; setting `y_t[30]` to any other numeric value yields the same error. If you supply a matrix (`y_t`) to the `y` argument, that causes an error. In your second attempt, you turned the matrix into a vector (`y_t[-30]` will turn the matrix into a vector and remove the 30th element). E.g., try:

```
> class(y_t)
[1] "matrix" "array" 
> class(y_t[-30])
[1] "numeric"
> sample_lasso <- train(method = "glmnet", x = x_t, y = y_t[ , 1]) # works as expected
```

As an aside, make sure to set the random seed before you generate data and fit models depending on cross validation.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my error. I was instinctively turning my response variable into a column vector as some of the other models I'm working with required it. I really appreciate your fast and concise response!

Comment: @Andrew You're welcome! If you accept the answer, the question can be marked as resolved.